# How to append forms dynamically in Flask WTForms?

Tags: jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to add forms to a page in real time, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Let's say that this is the class of my form:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    my_field = StringField()
```

This is the html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="addNewForm">Add new form</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Which also includes this script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       var form = '{{ form }}'
       $("document").ready(function () {
            $("#addNewForm").click(function () {
                $("body").append(form)
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

Once I press the button I get back something like:

> <forms.MyForm object at 0x000001C198CE5040>

I tried to extract the form HTML in order to pass it as an a string of html, but I can't find a way to do it (and suspect that there must be a better way).

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to add the same form multiple times or different forms to your page?

Comment: @ErnstBusch Here I was talking about the same form multiple times, but the page does include several different forms which may appear several times.

Comment: Some time ago i needed to append the same form multiple times and managed it by using wtf fieldlist. See https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/?highlight=fieldlist#wtforms.fields.FieldList Maby this could help you?

Comment: The solution to your scenario is indeed to use FieldList with the "append_entry()" method.
My problem is a little different, because I'm trying to add multiple possible types of form-fields so that the latest one appears last.
Currently I'm only able to have a separate FieldList for every FormField type, and whenever I add a new one it appears at the end of its own type's list, and not at the bottom of the page.
FieldList is by definition used for one Form type, so I'm kind of stuck.